# Conditional cast from 'ViewController' to 'AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate' always succeeds

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to implement a barcode scanner class in swift4, the app runs properly but I have an issue on set delegate;

```swift
let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self as? AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedCodeTypes
```

and i have this issue on "self as?"

> "Conditional cast from 'ViewController' to
>   'AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate' always succeeds"

how can I properly deal between these two objects?

Comment: You need to implement the `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` method in class which confirms this

Comment: If you already wrote: `extension or class ViewController: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate`, you don't need the `as? AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` in `self as? AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate`.